# Itext7 Checkbox checking error

Tags: c#, winforms, checkbox, itext7

I am filling out a premade PDF-Form programatically, using WinForms / C#.
Textfields are working as intended, but for a few days now Checkboxes are acting up, though the same code worked before.

I am getting an exception:

`System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'`

Originating from the "toSet.SetValue ..." line of code.

```
if (radioHVZANein.Checked)
                {
                    fields.TryGetValue("HVZANein", out toSet);
                    toSet.SetValue("Yes");
                }
```

I checked that the "HVZANein" Checkbox exists, checked that "Yes" is a valid value to set it to. Setting the correct value to the existing field still causes the error. 
(Which visual studio had helpfully displayed on the next line of code, not the one that actually triggers it)

What did I do wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Edit: [PDF](https://www.mediafire.com/file/e9ewgkwgu5tdrk3/Besichtigungs%20Vordruck.pdf)in question [ODS Source of the PDF](https://www.mediafire.com/file/3e99p9qtx87mp6m/Besichtigungs%20Vordruck.ods)

Comment: What i checked:

1) fields exists and contains all the fields it should, including "HVZANein"
2) TryGetValue works and sets "toSet" correctly.
3) "Yes" is an accepted Value for "HVZANein"

Comment: Please share the pdf in question.

Comment: Linked in the original Post, with the .ods from which it was created and where the Fields Name can be seen.

Though i did test it in the code, and the field is found by "TryGetValue" and self-identifies "Yes" to be a legitimate Value, hence my confusion why setting that Value causes an exception.

Comment: I just tested your piece of code (made self contained in a most plausible way) with your sample PDF and it executed just fine, the result being a checked "Nein" for "Halteverbotszone". Thus, there appears to be an issue in your remaining code or your environment.

Comment: Thanks for the comment and effort.
Seems weird to me, because i already tested document creation, flattening and printing on its own (works) and then did nothing but un-comment the lines shown above (getting exception).

So its basically proven that in my code the environment works, only textfields work, but any access to checkboxes causes a freak exception.

Even though both the Box exists and tells me the input is valid.
I am at my wits end.

Comment: can you **a** indicate your exact iText version (probably there was a bug which meanwhile has been fixed... I use the most current version.) and **b** reduce your code to an [sscce](http://sscce.org) that still produces the issue?

Comment: Upgrading to the most current version was my first reaction to the bug.
That can however not really be the issue, as it started to happen in the same version in which it worked before.
I am now on the current version as well.
SSCCE coming up shortly, after i make a workaround happen.